# npm test fails with error for reactjs app created with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

For a [create-react-app](/questions/tagged/create-react-app) I have created some tests in a `__test__` folder at the same level as the `src`

After running `npm test` the project folder I get the following error

How can I fix this so that I can run my tests?

```
jenkins@VBOX:dashboard$ npm test

> react-scripts test --env=jsdom
Determining test suites to run...fs.js:1236
    throw error;
    ^
Error: watch /home/jenkins/dev/git-stash/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-jest/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/node_modules/babel-types/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/fn/symbol ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1234:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1262:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/jenkins/dev/git-stash/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:144:20)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/jenkins/dev/git-stash/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:353:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at /home/jenkins/dev/git-stash/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/sane/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at go$readdir$cb (/home/jenkins/dev/git-stash/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:149:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that nonsensical word in all caps at the end of the first line of every node error... that's an [*error code*](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/3d3d48d4b78d48e9b002660fc045ba8bb4a96af2/deps/uv/include/uv.h#L65). This one was `ENOSPC`, [which means "no space on drive"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=enospc).

i.e. your drive was full, You must've freed up space before running npm install again, and it was the former not the latter that fixed your problem.

Comment: Ha! Yes that makes sense. Accepting answer.

Comment: I was on a VM that I use as a docker host. It had a load of cached images that needed clearing down.

Comment: I ran into same ENOSPC error, but I had plenty of free disk and memory. Since I was using atom with nuclide (Linux), and that's known to be a resource hog, I quite atom, relaunched it, and the error went away.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes we hit the limit on the number of files we can watch simultaneously and we gains the error while having plenty of free space.

On Linux (Debian Wheezy, npm v3.10.10, node v6.10.2)  it can be fixed by trying `$ npm dedupe` first, and, if still necessary, by

`$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Credits go to [hexo.io](https://hexo.io/ru/docs/troubleshooting.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly same problem. and I solve this issue by installing newest npm. I got ENOSPC error with npm version 2.15.11. and it works well with v3.10.10.